# Select columns with eloquent on relations

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have two tables which look look like this:

```
Addresses
ID | first_name | last_name | street

Clients
ID | address_id | assignment_id | comment
```

Now I want to serach a name via a search input and an ajax on my address table. But only for clients. Means, I have to use the laravel relationships. I have already set it up:

```
Address Model:

    public function clients()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Client');
    }

Client Model:

    public function address()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Address');
    }
```

What I want to get retuned is the ID of the CLIENTS table, the first name and last name of the address table for each client. This is my query so far:

```
$clients = Address::whereHas('clients', function ($query) use ($searchString){
                $query->select("id AS clientID")->where('last_name', 'like', '%'.$searchString.'%');
            })->get();
```

However, I don't get how I can pick the ID from the client table.. `$query->select("id AS clientID")` this isn't working..

How can I pick the ID of the client table and search the first name as well on the address table?

Kind regards

Comment: in result your need Address model with client_id?

Comment: Yes! - Cause I store all addresses from clients, suppliers and co in one table. But I want to have the client_id cause I need the client_id to access other tables etc

Comment: why you cant do this ??? Client::where('last_name', 'like', '%'.$searchString.'%')->get();

Comment: Cause last name ist stored in addresses. I definitly need to join the addresses table where the id of the address table is the address_id in the clients table!

Comment: Your schema above specifically states that `last_name` is on the addresses table.

Comment: @AlexHarris I don't get you...

Answer (score 0):

Having a little bit of trouble understanding exactly what you need. Does this solve your problem?

```
$addresses = Address::whereHas('clients')
     ->with('clients')
     ->where('last_name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
     ->get();

$result = $addresses->map(function($address) {
    return [
        'first_name' => $address->first_name,
        'last_name' => $address->last_name,
        'ids' => $address->clients->pluck('id')
    ];
});
```